# Keep domain on separate server?

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, domain, ip

is it possible to move a site to a new server while keeping the domain on the old server? So, the site would have a new IP but the domain is still hosted on the old server without changing the DNS records. Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with the terms "site" and "domain" here? Are you referring to web site versus domain name server? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to move my site to a new server without changing the current DNS records. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: You would need to change the A record for the site, not the NS records. If you're running your own name server, you really need to read up on how these things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can move the website to a new server without moving the DNS zone.

Comment: How exactly can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your goal is to migrate an existing web site to a new web server.

If your new server has a new address, DNS records will need to be updated internally and externally (if applicable) to reflect this change.

Comment: How can I move the website to a new server without moving the DNS zone? That's exactly what I want. Many thanks.